# Convert Json to data class kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, coroutine

Im a  newcomer into android development world. Im using retrofit and coroutines. Trying convert the next json object into a data class.
`

```
{
        "name": {
            "common": "Peru",
            "official": "Republic of Peru",
            "nativeName": {
                "aym": {
                    "official": "Piruw Suyu",
                    "common": "Piruw"
                },
                "que": {
                    "official": "Piruw Ripuwlika",
                    "common": "Piruw"
                },
                "spa": {
                    "official": "República del Perú",
                    "common": "Perú"
                }
            }
        },
        "tld": [
            ".pe"
        ],
        "cca2": "PE",
        "ccn3": "604",
        "cca3": "PER",
        "cioc": "PER",
        "independent": true,
        "status": "officially-assigned",
        "unMember": true,
        "currencies": {
            "PEN": {
                "name": "Peruvian sol",
                "symbol": "S/ "
            }
        },
        "idd": {
            "root": "+5",
            "suffixes": [
                "1"
            ]
        },
        "capital": [
            "Lima"
        ],
        "altSpellings": [
            "PE",
            "Republic of Peru",
            "República del Perú"
        ],
        "region": "Americas",
        "subregion": "South America",
        "languages": {
            "aym": "Aymara",
            "que": "Quechua",
            "spa": "Spanish"
        },
        "latlng": [
            -10.0,
            -76.0
        ],
        "landlocked": false,
        "borders": [
            "BOL",
            "BRA",
            "CHL",
            "COL",
            "ECU"
        ],
        "area": 1285216.0,
        "demonyms": {
            "eng": {
                "f": "Peruvian",
                "m": "Peruvian"
            },
            "fra": {
                "f": "Péruvienne",
                "m": "Péruvien"
            }
        },
        "population": 32971846,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC-05:00"
        ],
        "continents": [
            "South America"
        ],
        "flags": {
            "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/pe.png",
            "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/pe.svg"
        },
        "capitalInfo": {
            "latlng": [
                -12.05,
                -77.05
            ]
        }
    }
```

`Im facing this problem: Some of the atributes change depending on the country, for Peru case lenguages json object has three items and currencies json has a PEN Item but as you can see`

```
{
        "name": {
            "common": "Germany",
            "official": "Federal Republic of Germany",
            "nativeName": {
                "deu": {
                    "official": "Bundesrepublik Deutschland",
                    "common": "Deutschland"
                }
            }
        },
        "tld": [
            ".de"
        ],
        "cca2": "DE",
        "ccn3": "276",
        "cca3": "DEU",
        "cioc": "GER",
        "independent": true,
        "status": "officially-assigned",
        "unMember": true,
        "currencies": {
            "EUR": {
                "name": "Euro",
                "symbol": "€"
            }
        },
        "idd": {
            "root": "+4",
            "suffixes": [
                "9"
            ]
        },
        "capital": [
            "Berlin"
        ],
        "altSpellings": [
            "DE",
            "Federal Republic of Germany",
            "Bundesrepublik Deutschland"
        ],
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Western Europe",
       "languages": {
            "deu": "German"
        },
        
        "latlng": [
            51.0,
            9.0
        ],
        "landlocked": false,
        "borders": [
            "AUT",
            "BEL",
            "CZE",
            "DNK",
            "FRA",
            "LUX",
            "NLD",
            "POL",
            "CHE"
        ],
        "area": 357114.0,
        "demonyms": {
            "eng": {
                "f": "German",
                "m": "German"
            },
            "fra": {
                "f": "Allemande",
                "m": "Allemand"
            }
        },
        "flag": "",
        "maps": {
            "googleMaps": "https://goo.gl/maps/mD9FBMq1nvXUBrkv6",
            "openStreetMaps": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51477"
        },
        "population": 83240525,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "continents": [
            "Europe"
        ],
        "flags": {
            "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/de.png",
            "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/de.svg"
        },
        "capitalInfo": {
            "latlng": [
                52.52,
                13.4
            ]
        }
    }
```

`

In the german case, lengagues json just has one item and currencies json has an EUR item. You can also see that name json changes. How should I do that convertion to data class using kotlin?

Ive tried to search for solutions but havent really found anything that fits my case.

Comment: Have `languages` be a `Map<String, String>`. Have `currencies` be a `Map<String, Currency>`, where `Currency` is a separate data class that has `name` and `symbol`.

Comment: You can also check the country and then parse the JSON subset into a specific data class for that country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create data classes like this:

```
data class Name(
    val common: String,
    val official: String,
    val nativeName: Map<String, NativeName>,
)

data class NativeName(
    val official: String,
    val common: String,
)
```

Also currensies in base data class will be like this:

```
val currencies: Map<String, Currency>
```

And class Currency should look like this:

```
data class Currency(
    val name: String,
    val symbol: String,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the json to kotlin dataclass plugin it will convert raw json to dataclasses for you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIEac.png)